# How to BuddyPress and Avada - Profile Page Customization?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

With Buddypress and Avada theme the profile page can not be customized. The Members page has been assigned to BuddyPress and can be setup through Avada, located at domain.com/members/

But the user page and profile located at

- domain.com/members/username/
- domain.com/members/username/profile

do not respond to the Avada Layout for the Content page region.

Has someone an idea on how to style the user or profile page?

1.) I've assigned the members page to a Avada Layout, also assigned all relevant Children pages.
2.) Enabled Global Sidebars, enabled legacy widgets - setup a widget area for the members pages, which works on all pages except the BuddyPress User and Profile page.

There is one solution when using Elementor and BuddyBuilder https://staxwp.com/how-to-create-custom-buddypress-member-profile-layouts/

But how can we do this when using Avada with BuddyPress, to customize the user and profile page?

Comment: Did you find any solution or did you change to Elementor? I am familiar with Avada so I would like to continue using it. It would be great to resolve this issue.